# php web infinite loop - how to stop

Tags: php, infinite-loop

I need to write php code to routinely check for the feed of a specific website and send email to users if there is something new. The php code should run forever when it is started. However, my problem is that sometimes, my client want to manually turn off the script without using terminal. Can I stop a php script using another script or what can I do for this case?

Client only give me ftp access to an apache server, so I cannot use some other techniques like Python and Perl or terminal, which I believe should be easier for this task

Comment: You cannot use python/perl, so there's no reason to put those in the question's tags.

Comment: Can you make you use of cronjobs? An infinite running php script will load up your cpu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a file.
make your script check presence of some file, say, `stop.flag` in every iteration
if so - stop it

Comment: thanks, another stupid question, what happens if I already created an infinite php script?What should I do? I cannot delete that file or stop it by anyway. I cannot have any access to client's host but I can give them instruction

Comment: @vodkhang 4 mbut can't you send them another version, can you?